# Microsoft Active Directory Authenticate with Centos

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap

I'm having trouble trying to understand how I can authenticate a user without having to explicitly enter the administrator's credentials.

I have successfully set up a secure connection using LDAP over SSL and I can retrieve a users profile by entering in the terminal:

ldapsearch -x -D cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local -H ldaps://dc.domain.local -W 'sAMAccountName=smithd'

This prompts me for the admin password and it pulls the requested user info.

How I can authenticate a user without having to explicitly enter the administrator's credentials?

Should I be using Winbind? Samba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically with LDAP, you do not log in ("bind") as the *administrator* but as the *user*.

Try `ldapsearch -x -D cn=your-user,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local -H ldaps://dc.domain.local -W 'sAMAccountName=smithd'` and if the search succeeds, you user has been authenticated. In AD, a user's *CN* value may not be immediately obvious and is usually not equal to the *sAMAccountName* (grrr). Try using an LDAP search to find the *CN* values for your users:

`ldapsearch -x -D cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local -H ldaps://dc.domain.local -W 'objectclass=inetorgperson' cn`

This will give you a list of users and their *CN* values. Now you can try to bind with one of thos users using the *CN* value in `cn=<user cn>,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local`.

Furthermore, Centos can use `pam_ldap` to authenticate users against an LDAP directory, also AD. You can find more info here: http://www.padl.com/OSS/pam_ldap.html

For a `pam_ldap` setup, you will probably need a proxy user whose account name and password are in the configuration file, but this does not have to be an administrative user normally. This user will be used by `pam_ldap` to locate the actual user trying to log in, after which the *bind* is performed with that actual user.

Be aware that many people from the LDAP world automatically assume that you understand all the basics, so there might be a steep learning curve.

Comment: I entered: `ldapsearch -x -D cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local -H ldaps://dc.domain.local -W 'sAMAccountName=smithd'` but returns the following: `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49) additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1` -- I know I am using the correct username and password so I will look into pam_ldap to authenticate against AD.

Comment: That's because `cn=users,dc=domain,dc=local` is not the username, but the container where the users reside (by default). Try adding the username for _smithd_. You can lookup that name in the AD 'Users and Computers', it should be something like this: `cn=D Smith,cn=users,...`

Comment: Okay - that makes sense. The Distinquished name for the user is `CN=David Smith ,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local` so my full ldapsearch command is `ldapsearch -x -D CN=David Smith,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local -H ldaps://dc.domain.local -W 'sAMAccountName=smithd'` but still returns the same _Invalid credentials_ error.

Comment: Hm, try to add quotes around the user DN, because the space in `David Smith` might be playing tricks on you.

Comment: That works!!! I used quotes around the user name. So the command `ldapsearch -x -D CN='David Smith',CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local -H ldaps://dc.domain.local -W 'sAMAccountName=smithd'` returns the user info which means the authentication is successful. Now my next hurdle is to determine why my php code is unable to connect. I will submit a separate post for this issue. Thanks mvreijn!!!

Comment: Anytime. Will keep an eye out for your question :)